# My new div isn't being recognized on my site, why?

Tags: html, liquid

I sliced and diced an existing class: `product__info` and created a new one: `product__purchase` under the same parent class `product product--` as such:

```
<section class="page-width section-{{ section.id }}-padding">
  <div class="product product--{{ section.settings.media_size }} product--{{ section.settings.gallery_layout }} grid grid--3-col {% if product.media.size > 0 %}grid--3-col-tablet{% else %}product--no-media{% endif %}">
    <div class="grid__item product__media-wrapper">
    </div>
    <div class="product__purchase-wrapper grid__item{% if settings.page_width > 1400 and section.settings.media_size == "small" %} product__purchase-wrapper--extra-padding{% endif %}">
      <div id="Product-{{ section.id }}" class="product__purchase-container{% if section.settings.enable_sticky_info %} product__purchase-container--sticky{% endif %}">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product__info-wrapper grid__item{% if settings.page_width > 1400 and section.settings.media_size == "small" %} product__info-wrapper--extra-padding{% endif %}">
      <div id="Product-{{ section.id }}" class="product__purchase-container{% if section.settings.enable_sticky_info %} product__purchase-container--sticky{% endif %}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>
```

However, this new section: `product__purchase` is not appearing on my development site, only the two original classes: `product__media` and `product__info`.

What I see on my development site:

[image: What I see on my development site]

Does anyone have any idea why this is the case? Could it be that I used the same id `id=Product-{{ section.id}} ...` for the new div class?

As always, thanks for your time :-)

Comment: Did you hard refresh and check? Caching could be the reason

Comment: @ArseneWenger great suggestion but unfortunately, this didn't work